# How to load non-english fonts to android

Tags: android, android-fonts

I have recently come across a situation while developing an app where sometimes non-english fonts in Android browser are appearing just as mere rectangle boxes.

Can anybody give me an idea on how to enable or load these non-english fonts in Android browser..?

Please Note: I have read the settings to do in Opera Mini browser for no-english fonts, but I want the non-english fonts in Android browser.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

it means that the ttf fonts on your device do not support your lanaguage.
unless u have a rooted device not much you can do about it.
if you have a rooted device you need to get a .ttf file the includes your language and put it un the /system/font folder of your device (don't forget ro remount for rw access: remount -t yaff2 -o remount, rw /dev/xxx /system).

Answer (score 0):

Android allows you to package custom fonts within your apk. You can place the font file in your assests folder and use it in your application. [Using Custom Fonts with Android Application](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/) provides a good tutorial.

The code looks somewhat like this:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/CustomFont.otf");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```